# JavaFX/SceneBuilder - Changing only PART of a Scene

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm a total newbie in JavaFX and I haven't found any tutorial/answer about this matter.

So basically what I'd like to do is change only part of my Scene. I want to keep a static menu bar at the top and only change the bottom part according to which menu button is being clicked. Which means I need different FXML files and Controller classes for every "page".

Looking at the available JavaFX features I thought SubScene would do the job. But after further investigation it seems that SubScenes are made for 3D stuff? So I really have no clue what I should do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [`BorderPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) may be useful in this situation.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson But wouldn't that require me to MANUALLY remove and add the childrens of the BorderPane? I'm searching for a "SubScene" where I could call some method like .setRoot() to attach a SceneBuilder-generated FXML file.

Comment: @M.Benamar: `SubScene.setRoot` or `BorderPane.setCenter` shouldn't be much of a difference regarding complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing parts of the scene is easy. In the main scene, you put a container in which you dynamically load different views. Here's an example following your description for a general "static" menu:

This is the basic view. In `mainView`, the different views are loaded (default is view_a.fxml) and are changed from the View > Show View X menu. The IDs I have assigned to the individual `MenuItem` are the names of the `FXML` files to load.

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="View">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem fx:id="view_a" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show View A" onAction="#handleChangeView"/>
                        <MenuItem fx:id="view_b" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show View B" onAction="#handleChangeView"/>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <BorderPane fx:id="mainView">
            <center>
                <fx:include source="view_a.fxml"/>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

This is one of the views (view_a.fxml). The other is the same, so I will not show it. In these views, it's interesting that I do not specify a controller because I later use the controller on the main frame (this is good for small things, but for big projects it is nice to use different controllers).

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <Label text="View A"/>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The controller itself is nothing special. It just adds one ".fxml" to the ID of the option that is selected, loads the `FXML` file with the resulting name, and puts it in the `mainView` center

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainView;

    @FXML
    private void handleChangeView(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            String menuItemID = ((MenuItem) event.getSource()).getId();

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(menuItemID + ".fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);

            mainView.setCenter(loader.load());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to use seperate Controllers how would I pass the appropriate controller in the loader.setController(); line?

Comment: @user3317592, separate viewer controllers? You do not need to give a controller at all. Simply declare your controllers in the `view_a.fxml` and `view_b.fxml` views. Eventually, you might consider calling back to the main stage controller.

Comment: I should have realised that! Thanks :) Also by calling back to the main controller do you mean passing that as a parameter somehow to the other controllers? I suppose we would do that to access the methods of the main controller?

Comment: @user3317592 yes, it is very common for different controllers to communicate with each other. in the above statement you can use `loader.getController()` to get the new viewer controller to inject the data you would need.

Comment: @mrmcwolf I don't get how another controller will set the view. Do you suggest that BorderPane or primary Controller reference should be passed to any new controller, so it could call a method to replace center in border pane?