# mvvmFX: Changing Part of a Scene on Runtime

Tags: javafx, mvvm, mvvmfx

I'm building a JavaFX Application with [mvvmFX](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX).

I have a scene with two panes. Both panes should include any.fxml . I would like to change the included panes at runtime.

[image: picture]

So I've found this solution: [JavaFX/SceneBuilder - Changing only PART of a Scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464137/javafx-scenebuilder-changing-only-part-of-a-scene) and tried to apply it.

So far, so good. Pane2 is displaying `any.fxml`, but unfortunately, the controller/viewModel is not getting loaded. At least it seems so, `any.fxml` contains a label which should get modified by the viewModel.

If O add `fx:controller="anyVM"` to `any.fxml` and include it via `fx:include source="any.fxml"` in `pane2.fxml` everything is working fine. But it's important for me to change it on runtime.

I would be glad if somebody knows a solution how to achieve this.

This is the View of my Main-Scene:

```
public class Scene implements FxmlView<SceneVM>, Initializable {    
    @FXML
    private BorderPane pane2;

    @InjectViewModel
    private SceneVM sceneVM;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {    
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("any.fxml"));
        loader.setController(anyVM.class);

        try {
            pane2.setCenter(loader.load());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

This is pane2 in scene.fxml:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="pane2" layoutX="846.0" prefHeight="547.0" prefWidth="521.0">
    <center>            <!--<fx:include source="any.fxml" />-->
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

This is the ViewModel / Controller

```
@Singleton
public class anyVM implements ViewModel {    
    private StringProperty lbl = new SimpleStringProperty("27");

    public StringProperty getLbl(){
        return basementViewKesselTempLbl;
    }

    public void setLbl(String message){
        lbl.set(message);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code of `initialize` you are using `FXMLLoader` which is part of standard JavaFX. However, to load a mvvmFX View with all setup logic you have to use mvvmFX's `FluentViewLoader`. 
The `FluentViewLoader` uses `FXMLLoader` internally but does a whole lot more operations like injecting ViewModels into their Views.

So your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    ViewTuple<AnyView, AnyViewModel> viewTuple = FluentViewLoader.fxmlView(AnyView.class).load();

    pane2.setCenter(viewTuple.getView());  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel, exactly what i needed! Works fine now.